# Is it allowed to use other tags inside <title>?

Tags: html, seo, semantic-markup

Is it correct practice or valid syntax to use other tags inside a `<title>`?

An example for multi-language title

```
<html lang=en>
<title>Some title in English and a <i lang=fr>word in French</i></title>
```

Comment: un mot en Francais, peut-etre? (Sorry, no French keyboard, so no accents or cedillas.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

See http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.4.2:

> Titles may contain character entities (for accented characters, special characters, etc.), but **may not contain other markup (including comments)**.

(my emphasis)

Comment: I've just found a legitimate need for markup inside `<title>`. Chrome uses the `notranslate` class value as an indication to not translate the text inside. If you wanted some part of the title not to be translated, you could do this `<title>Page about <p class=notranslate>Brand Name</p></title>`. Unfortunately it doesn't work. You can prevent the whole title from being translated or none of it, but not parts of it.

Answer (score 2):

No, it may not

http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/TITLE.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use whatever you want, but it will all be used as title string, without any additional parsing/processing from the browser (if that's what you expect). RFC says you have to resist from placing markup in title, though.

Comment: No, it will not work. No markup is recognized there, so e.g. the part `<i lang=fr>` will appear literally in contexts where the `title` element content is used, like tab labels.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela this is what I wrote. Read my comment again. You will see your markup on page title (usually on browser window title) unprocessed.

Comment: you wrote that ”it will work”. It won’t, because the purpose is clearly to mark some words as French, not to make `<i lang=fr>` appear. (And a reference to RFC is irrelevant; the last and only HTML version defined in a RFC was HTML 2.0.)

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela but in previous sentence I said it will be used as regular string and not parsed. Edited my answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR:** The `<title>` tag (1) must contain text (it must not be empty), (2) must *only* contain text (i.e. no other elements), and (3) must contain text that is not just white-space.

---

[In HTML 5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/document-metadata.html#the-title-element), the **Content Model** of the `title` element is:

> Text that is not inter-element white space.

where **inter-element white space** is any Text node that is either empty or only contains sequences of **space characters**:

> - U+0020 SPACE
> - U+0009 CHARACTER TABULATION (tab)
> - U+000A LINE FEED (LF)
> - U+000C FORM FEED (FF)
> - U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN (CR)