# Comments within the title tag are being added to the title

Tags: html, comments

Comments written within title tag in the HTML are showing in the title bar of the web page.

I have tried to open my html file in chrome and edge both are showing the same output, i.e. showing the comment on the title bar of the web page. My question is does the title tag ignore the comments written within it, or  have I done something wrong this.

I would expect that the browser should ignore the comment:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> <!--This tag stores the meta data of the page-->
        <title> <!--This tag handles the title bar of the web page-->
           Hello           
        </title>
    </head>
    <body><!--This tag handles all the content/body of the web page -->
        Hello! World...<br>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, if you see the comment in the title being displayed by the browser then you already know your answer. You should also validate your HTML to make sure it's correct syntactically (it is). And then check the standards. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168806/is-it-allowed-to-use-other-tags-inside-title

Answer (score 3):

It is correct syntactically.

However, Do test it with different browsers.

All of the popular browsers will display the comments, `"<!--"` and `"-->"` included, within the title.

**A few guidelines and tips for composing good titles:**

- Avoid one- or two-word titles. Use a descriptive phrase, or a term-definition pairing for glossary or reference-style pages.
- Search engines typically display about the first 55–60 characters of a page title. Text beyond that may be lost, so try not to have titles longer than that. If you must use a longer title, make sure the important parts come earlier and that nothing critical is in the part of the title that is likely to be dropped.
- Avoid special characters when possible; not all browsers will display them the same way. For example, "<" often winds up displayed in the window title bar as "<" (the HTML less-than entity).
- Don't use "keyword blobs." If your title is just a list of words, algorithms often reduce your page's position in the search results.
- Try to make sure your titles are as unique as possible within your own site. Duplicate—or near-duplicate—titles can contribute to inaccurate search results.

For More Info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/title

Comment: why ? does not it violates the meaning of comments.comments are meant to be hidden from output.

Comment: @Srivstvanik Why would you be putting comments in the document's title?

Comment: @Srivstvanik I think you are putting many assumptions here as to the behavior of comments in HTML, and how browsers support them.

Comment: i was just trying to do something new. In this way i may learn something new.

Comment: @j08691 thanks I got my answer.[link]https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.4.2

Answer (score 0):

Your codes are correct, I think you should try running it again.

I use same code and the output was Hello! World...